# data output after receiving it in fetch

Tags: javascript, promise, output, fetch

I apologize for the stupid question, please tell me how to transfer data from fetch (). then () to another function.

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
var urlZaprosHttp = 'http://ietf.org/';
var urlZaprosHttps = 'https://ietf.org/';


const fetch = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const protocol = url.startsWith('https') ? https : http;
  protocol.get(url, res => {
    if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      const { statusCode, statusMessage } = res;
      reject(new Error(`Status Code: ${statusCode} ${statusMessage}`));
    }
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    const lines = [];
    res.on('data', chunk => lines.push(chunk));
    res.on('end', () => resolve(lines.join()));
  });
});

// Usage

fetch(urlZaprosHttps)
  .then(body => console.log(body))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Call the function in .then by passing the parameters into the function you want and access the parameters in the function.

Comment: i.e. ... you're already calling a function with the data ... `console.log(body)` ... just call a *different* function with `body` as the argument

Comment: Can I not call a function inside fetch?

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply call another function from within `then()` and do whatever you want with your data in that function:

```
fetch(urlZaprosHttps)
  .then(body => someOtherFunction(body))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const myFunc = (data) => {
 console.log(data)
} 

   fetch(urlZaprosHttps)
      .then(myFunc(data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

In the then you can pass in a function and the data returned will be passed to that function, like in my example.

Comment: Can I not call a function inside fetch?

Comment: Do you mean declare it inside fetch ? , because we're already calling it inside fetch. @NikD